# Yellow highlight in Agda

Tags: warnings, agda

I write the below code in Agda.

```
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open import Data.Unit

data  : Set where
    tt : 
    ff : 

test_a : tt ≡ tt
test_a = refl

test_b : ff ≡ ff
test_b = refl
```

When I load the above code, I get yellow highlight with

```
tt ≡ tt
```

at line 8. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: I'm sorry not to include all the imports. To use3237465, thank you for pointing out. To Cactus, thank you for adding all the imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you imported `Data.Unit` or `Data.Unit.Base` which introduced another `tt` (namely the inhabitant of `⊤`), so Agda is confused about which one to choose. You can write

```
test_a : .tt ≡ tt
test_a = refl
```

or

```
import Function

test_a : ( ∋ tt) ≡ tt
test_a = refl
```